# Is VirtualBox 6.1 able to be installed correctly on Windows 11?

Tags: virtualbox, centos, guest-additions

Is VirtualBox 6.1 (Version 6.1.32 r149290 (Qt5.6.2)) able to be installed correctly on Windows 11? 
I manage to install CentOS 7.9.2009 in VirtualBox 6.1 (on Windows 11 host), but whatever I do (e.g., following [modprobe vboxguest failed](https://superuser.com/questions/412527/modprobe-vboxguest-failed)) I fail to install Guest Additions, where the log shows only:

```
[root@ansible-server ~# cat /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log
modprobe vboxquest failed
```

**Steps taken:**
The following are installed on the guest VM:

```
[rbarak@ansible-server~]$ rpm -qa | sort | egrep 'dkms|binutils|gcc|make|patch|libgomp|glibc-headers|glibc-devel|kernel-headers|kernel-devel'
binutils-2.27-44.base.el7_9.1.x86 64
dkms-3.0.3-1.el7.noarch
gcc-4.8.5-44.el7. x86 64
glibc-devel-2.17-325.el7 9.x86 64
glibc-headers-2.17-325.e17 9.x86 64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86 64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86 64
kpatch-0.6.1-6.el7.noarch-libgcc-4.8.5-44.e17. x86 64
libgomp-4.8.5-44.e17.x86_64
make-3.82-24.el7.x86_64
patch-2.7.1-12.el7_7.x86_64
speech-dispatcher-0.7.1-15.el7.x86 64
speech-dispatcher-python-0.7.1-15.el7.x86 64
[rbarak@ansible-server~]$ uname
3.10.0-1160.e17.x86 64
```

After these RPMs were installed, the guest VM is restarted.

But, Guest Additions installation fails:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good
Uncompressing VirtualBox 6.1.32 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 6.1.32 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules. This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:  /bin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:  /bin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Kernel headers not found for target kernel
3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64. Please install them and execute /sbin/revboxadd setup
modprobe vboxquest failed
The log file /var/log/vboxadd-setup. log may contain further information
Press Return to close this window...
```

Drag'N'Drop is set to bidirectional:

[image: Drag'N'Drop is set to bidirectional]

The Kernel Headers and the active kernel seem to match:

```
[rbarak@ansible-server ~]$ uname
3.10.0-1160.e17.x86 64
[rbarak@ansible-server ~]$ rom -qa | grep 'kernel-kernel-devel-3.10.0-1160.59.1.e17.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.e17.x86_64
kernel-debug-devel-3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64
[rbarak@ansible-server~1$
```

Comment: Please add the entire steps you've taken to install the guest additions.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Copy the console text and paste here, not in images

Comment: The current version of VirtualBox supports Windows 11 per the release notes for it

Comment: @mashuptwice: see `Edit 1`

Comment: @phuclv: I add screenshots because AFAIK one needs Guest Additions for cut-and-paste to work.

Comment: Check if the kernel headers match your current kernel version with `ls -l /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r) `

Comment: @mashuptwice: see `Edit 2`

Comment: Please run `yum update` and try again.

Comment: @phuclv I converted the images to text in macOS and it should now be cleaner and easier to handle. Images linked here for reference: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoAP6.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEdl9.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGAAg.png) and [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW1FF.png).

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with the OS running on the HOST. So there is no relation with Windows 11 at all. Your problem is in the guest installation.

Comment: @mashuptwice: that did the trick. Once I did the `yum update`, rebooted the machine, and re-run the `guest additions` installation, it now works. Thanks, @mashuptwice.

Comment: Glad that I could help, I've added the comment as an answer.

Comment: @boardrider Happy this was solved, but please [do not edit your question to thank someone for solving your issue](https://superuser.com/posts/1712663/revisions). Encourage them to post an answer and then simply check that answer off as the answer and additionally upvote it if you wish. This community is not a forum or chat board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems you've already installed the kernel headers via `yum install kernel-devel`.

You probably need to update your system with `yum update` to fetch the current kernel header package.